# Android - Error Setting Up Content Type When Uploading Images

Tags: php, android, image-uploading, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to upload an image to a PHP server from an Android application.

I'm using the httpcore and httpmime libraries.

The problem is that the image is being uploaded, but the server doesn't recognize it as JPEG image. I need to set the ContentType for the image, but I can't find a way of doing it.

Here's the method I'm using -

```
   public void uploadImage(String imagePath) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
   {
        // Client-side HTTP transport library
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // using POST method
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost("URL_TO_PHP_SERVER");
        try {

            File file = new File(imagePath);

            MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            multiPartEntityBuilder.addTextBody("user_id", userID);

            multiPartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("photo", file);

            httpPostRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntityBuilder.build());

            // Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);

            // receive response as inputStream
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            String result;
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
            Log.v("result", result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
```

Comment: Please also  post ur logcat

Comment: Mann, I print the response from the server(there's no actual error from the Android part), and it reads that the type of the file unknown, and the server only accepts JPEG and PNG files(although I am sending a JPEG image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addBinaryBody method has several signatures. There are ones where you can add the contentType as follows:

```
String filename = "imageName.jpg"
multiPartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("photo", file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, filename);
```

Here the [Documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html)

And if you want to come up with another ContentType you can create your own do it as follows:

```
public static final ContentType MYCONTENTTYPE = ContentType.create(
           "image/jpeg", Consts.ISO_8859_1);
```

Here the [Documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html#create(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA Does not work, I need to set it as "image/jpeg", but the ContentType class does not provide this option.